# How to remove default sidebar items in file browser on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, file-management

Ubuntu has a number of default sidebar items in the file browser:

[image]

They are Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Videos in the left sidebar. I don't need these shortcuts. How do I remove them from the file browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove some of the default sidebar items by tweaking `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Check out: https://askubuntu.com/a/407940